# How do I use Devise to secure the delayed_job_web interface?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, delayed-job

I'm using the delayed_job_web gem to monitor delayed jobs. https://github.com/ejschmitt/delayed_job_web

It is accessible using this line in my routes.rb:

```
match "/delayed_job" => DelayedJobWeb, :anchor => false
```

Every other area of my site requires a login using the Devise gem.  How do I make this require a login too?

In the readme, they suggest adding the following to the config.rb:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  DelayedJobWeb.use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
    username == 'username'
    password == 'password'
  end
end
```

But that just uses plain text browser authentication.

UPDATE:
I tried something similar to the railscast on resque, and I think it's on the verge of working but giving me a redirect loop now:

```
  authenticate :admin do
    mount DelayedJobWeb, :at => "/delayed_job"
  end
```

Any thoughts on why would it be giving a redirect loop?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `authenticated` instead of `authenticate` as described here: http://excid3.com/blog/rails-tip-5-authenticated-root-and-dashboard-routes-with-devise/

Works for me!

Comment: That worked for me too.  It appears like the route doesnt exist if not logged in (does not redirect the login page), but if logged in everything works.  That's good enough for me. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is useful enough to be worth adding to the readme on the github project? All they suggest is http basic auth, which isn't really a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this define this inside `config/routes.rb` file

```
  authenticate_user = lambda do |request|   
     request.env['warden'].authenticate?
  end

  constraints authenticate_user do
    mount DelayedJobWeb, :at => "/delayed_job"
  end
```

Alternately if you have cancan for any other role management library you could do it something like [this](http://blog.arcath.net/2011/06/resque-cancan/)

I have used both of this in my applications to control access to resque-web depending on the needs of the application

Hope this help

Comment: I'm not using cancan so couldn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's 2017 I tried the other solutions and they didn't work, but the following admin check does work:

```
authenticated :user, -> user { user.admin? }  do
  mount DelayedJobWeb, at: "/delayed_job"
end
```